# git best practices for developing a code for two different devices

Tags: git, software-product-lines

I am developing an HTML app that will be
1. compiled using Phonegap Build
2. offered as pure web app on a www server

So the code will be mainly the same but there will small parts dedicated to either the first or second adaptation.

But the improvements on the base code will have to be pushed to both adaptations.

So should I use one git repo and create branches or should I use several repos?

I am new to git so could you please write the workflow commands?

Comment: I don't think that git is a proper tool to do what you want.

Comment: In agreement with @phoet , your workflow in `git` is a secondary interest. You should structure your project such that you have a device-neutral core (possibly in one subdirectory), and the separate device-specific sections (probably in separate subdirectories), and separate build inputs (`Makefiles` or targets in one `Makefile`, or other files if you're using `cmake` or `scons` or something else) for the two independent targets. You could certainly use separate `git` branches for development on the different components, though...

Comment: There is a whole computer science subfield on the question of how to do this in general, called "software product lines". I've never heard of anything useful coming out of it though!

Comment: @RobinGreen Aw, come on... *Nothing* useful? What about Pong? Missile Command? Snipe? Nethack? </snark>

Comment: They came out of software product lines research?

Comment: @RobinGreen Well, ok, maybe not... but they've at least been ported to different platforms through some vague semblance of similar methodology..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you still consider git, the usual way to address "common parts" is to:

- isolate them in their own repo
- reference said repos as **submodules** in a parent repo.

See [**Git Submodules**](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

That way, you can define two parent repos:

- one for app1, with a reference to the "common" repo, plus specific developments for app1
- one for app2, with a reference to the "common" repo, plus specific developments for app2